# The [forge] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki for [forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forge) defines it as:

> A software forge is a collaboration platform allowing collaborative software development over the Internet. A forge platform aggregates a set of applications with integrated Web interfaces, and generally hosts multiple independent projects. Software developers who are registered as contributors to the hosted projects can then use the various project management tools, and software development tools.

However, most of the questions tagged with it are referring to either MinecraftForge, a tool for Minecraft modding, or Trigger.io Forge, which is a cross platform app development tool of some kind. What's supposed to happen in situations like this?

Comment: **Disambiguate all the things!**  Mass retagging into tags that are better (new or already existing), one per *worth* topic covered by the ambiguous tag.